# Disable .net completely in a IIS6 Application Pool

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, application-pools

we're managing some web sites for our clients on our servers, some running Windows Server 2003 R2 and others running 2008 R2. In Windows Server 2008 R2, we can disable completely .NET framework usage for some application pools, which is great since most of our websites are still using classic ASP.

After some issues with classic ASP applications being configured to run as ASP.NET 4 in a CLR 2.0 pool, we wanted to do the same thing in IIS6 - that is, **have application pools without any .NET support.**

Is this a supported scenario in IIS6?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable .NET support completely across the whole of IIS, run

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -u
```

You'll need to run this for each version of the framework that you have installed. The executable is in %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.xxx

Once you've done that, you should find that there's no ASP.NET tab on the properties of a website in IIS. Be aware though that updates to the .NET framework can end up re-registering it in IIS.

If you server has some sites using ASP.NET and others just using Classic ASP, you can just put all the Classic ASP sites into their own AppPool and the .NET sites into theirs. As you've no doubt discovered, all applications in an AppPool must be configured to use the same version of the framework. I'm not aware of a way of disabling ASP.NET for a particular site.

Comment: I think that would disable it for all application pools, which may not be what they want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the first line of my response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the application pool, but for the web site, you could configure on the Home Directory tab > Configuration > Mappings tab, and remove every mapping that has an executable for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework....  usually for aspnet_isapi.dll.